# Create a folder in GitHub via the web interface

Tags: github

I want to add a new folder to my newly created GitHub repository without installing the windows setup. Is it possible to do so? I have gone through help which is saying to execute some commands to create a folder but I don't know where to write those commands.

I can't install a Windows setup because my office PC is restricted.

I know how to add files using the web app interface but not folders.

Comment: How did you create your repository then? What software do you use to manage git? Normally, creating a new folder within your repository is as easy as creating a new folder in the Windows Explorer, then doing a commit.

Comment: @user1781026 Let me explain this again.. I cant install the **windows setup** (which ofcourse makes the creating a folder easy).

Comment: @user1781026 Its alright. How to make new folders? Can you please explain it or direct me to a link.

Comment: Just right click, New - Folder, like you normally would create a folder on your computer. Afterwards, use "merge" to commit your files and folders into the repository when you have access to a git client.

Comment: @user1781026 nah!! not that.. I am asking How to add a new folder on the **web browser** (github account) not on computer.

Comment: Oooh, I see the problem now. You might be interested in a git web frontend of some sort, but I don't know how trustworthy they are, considering you are on a work computer. Check out this list to see if there's anything, I have never used these: [git.kernel.org Wiki about interfaces, frontends and tools](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools#Web_Interfaces) ([Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232186/how-to-create-a-github-branch-without-having-git-installed))

Comment: Talk to your office admin about changing your PC setup, you **should** **not** be managing your repos in the front end. The new add file feature is nifty but it's not meant *currently* to be the way to manage your files.

Comment: @phwd so It is not possible to create a folder on web interface.. right?

Comment: @phwd There could be some trick to achieve it.. I dont care if it is very long process.. please help.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is possible to create a new folder from the web interface, but it would require you to have at least one file within the folder when creating it.

When using the normal way of creating new files through the web interface, you can type in the folder into the file name to create the file within that new directory.

E.g. If I would like to create the file filename.md in a series of subfolders, I can do this *(taken from the GitHub Blog)*:
[image: With credits to GitHub]