# How can one upload files to GitHub via the web interface?

Tags: github

My question related to the Github.com web interface only. Similar to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36411/create-a-folder-in-github-via-the-web-interface) ([Create a folder in GitHub via the web interface](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36411/create-a-folder-in-github-via-the-web-interface)), is it possible to upload files to a GitHub repository using only the web interface?

I want to upload some jar files to a repository but I am currently using my work PC, where I cannot install any programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 2016 February you can use the new upload files feature.

> You’ll soon be able to skip the command line and upload files directly to your repositories without having to leave the browser. Repository uploads will be rolling out over the next few days, so if you can’t upload yet, sit tight.
>
> You can click the “Upload files” button in the toolbar at the top of the file tree.
>
> [image]
>
> Or, you can drag and drop files from your desktop onto the file tree.
>
> Or, you can drag and drop files from your desktop onto the file tree.
>
> [Gif file not supported by the SE upload.]
>
> Once you’ve added all the files you want to upload, you can commit them directly to your default branch or create a new branch and open a pull request. This will look familiar if you’ve used the “New file” button before.

[Source](https://github.com/blog/2105-upload-files-to-your-repositories).

Comment: Could you give a brief summary of the blog post so that the answer can be self-contained?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The question you linked shows a way to upload text files. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to upload binary files.

[Zapier](https://zapier.com/) seems to provide ways to upload files (via pull requests) from third party web-apps like Dropbox, Google Drive, … to Github. For Dropbox I found this:

- [Dropbox New File in Directory to Github Create Pull Request](https://zapier.com/zapbook/dropbox/github/10035/dropbox-new-file-in-directory-to-github-create-pull-request/)
- [GitHub Pull Request from Dropbox Files](https://zapier.com/zapbook/dropbox/github/3304/github-pull-request-from-dropbox-files/)

More connections between Github and other webapps, can be found here: https://zapier.com/app/explore?services=github.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Codenvy](https://codenvy.com/) to upload files to GitHub or Google App Engine.